# Searching for words, not a phrase in mysql < 5.6.4

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I'm looking for a way to search words in mysql table. Considering I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `q_news` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `short_content` text NOT NULL,
  `content` text NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(400) NOT NULL,
  `keywords` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ;
```

And in one of the records, in `title` field I have "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"

Now, I want to get this record, when looking for "quick lazy" - I can't use match against, because it's innoDb and mysql version is below 5.6.4. What's the solution then? The only thing which comes to my mind is :

```
select * from q_news where `title` like '%quick%%lazy%'
```

But somehow I don't like this solution, is there a better way?

ps. I didn't know how to phrase my question, so couldn't google it, sorry if this is duplicate.

Comment: Is there a reason for not using `LIKE` keyword in the query.? What do you mean by `I don't like this solution`.

Comment: Because I rather thought about some kind of regular expression, but not using match againsts. But I believe it's impossible.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
SELECT * FROM q_news WHERE `title` LIKE '%quick%' AND `title` LIKE '%lazy%'
```

Using 2 `LIKE` can solve your problem.

Comment: If you (Raptor) have about 100 words, should you use 100 LIKES?

Comment: Why not? It's still possible. (Better to use programming language to generate the SQL)

Comment: It makes very slow the query

Comment: Yes, text search is usually slow.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM q_news WHERE MATCH(title) AGAINST ('quick lazy');
```

Comment: I can't, my mysql version and innodb table doesn't allow this.

Comment: Read this link: http://www.percona.com/blog/2013/07/31/innodb-full-text-search-in-mysql-5-6-part-3/

Comment: are you using PHP with it?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but my mysql version is 5.1 and innodb full text searching was introduced in 5.6 - I can't use "match against". Yes, I'm using PHP.

Comment: Use a very nice PHP search engine library (Sphinx) it is very fast http://sphinxsearch.com